# How to get an error message instead of an integer in MQL5?

Tags: opencl, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to get the error message using `OpenCl` in `MQL5`.

```
int     cl_ctx;
if (  ( cl_ctx = CLContextCreate( CL_USE_ANY ) ) == INVALID_HANDLE )
{
      Print( "OpenCL not found: ", GetLastError() );

      float pr  = 2.0 / ( period + 1.0 );
      result[0] = (float)price[position] * pr + prev_value * ( 1 - pr );

      Print(  result[0] );
      return( result[0] );
}
```

I am getting the message as:

```
OpenCL not found: 5113
```

Now I do not know what this `5113` means. How I can get the message in human readable format that will help me debug my program effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In case your code received **`_LastError == 5113`**:

the documented human-readable explanation is this one:

> `ERR_OPENCL_TOO_MANY_OBJECTS     5113    Too many OpenCL objects`

Next time, better present a few "surrounding" lines via a copy/paste from the MT5-log, there are more details surrounding the Runtime Error incident.

All error-code definitions and explanations are kept both in documentation and in `< stderror.mqh >` file since ever.

Also may re-read the **[online documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/errorswarnings/errorcodes)** aids.

Lastl, but not least, always pre-clear `_LastError` state with a call to **`ResetLastError()`**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is amazing .. Yes, I forgot to free the object.. how silly of me... :) ;P

Comment: Yessssssss, resources management, resources management, resources management ... a must do duty ...